# Wifi is not working after update in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, updates, ath9k

Wifi interface is showing but it just won't connect. Here is the information related to wireless of my computer

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 30 Jul 2016 10:07 IST +0530

Booted last: 30 Jul 2016 09:26 IST +0530

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-92-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 20:42:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:05ea]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:020c]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0c45:649a Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13ee:0001 MosArt Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

dell_wmi               12761  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop            18133  0 
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
ath9k                 164164  0 
ath9k_common           13551  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              453856  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    28698  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              638901  1 ath9k
ath3k                  17414  0 
cfg80211              496328  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211
bluetooth             391136  23 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
wmi                    19177  1 dell_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       764     1  0 09:26 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JVP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=JVP | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=JVP | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SIT]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SIT | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=SIT | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/sbi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=sbi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=sbi | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/RailWire Wi-Fi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=RailWire Wi-Fi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=RailWire Wi-Fi | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AbhishekWifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=AbhishekWifi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=AbhishekWifi | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/C_LIBRARY]] (600 root)
[connection] id=C_LIBRARY | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=C_LIBRARY | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SETUP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SETUP | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=SETUP | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ADYYYXNob2todGM4NjUx]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ADYYYXNob2todGM4NjUx | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ADYYYXNob2todGM4NjUx | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/bsnl]] (600 root)
[connection] id=bsnl | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=bsnl | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Android]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Android | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Android | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CAMPUS]] (600 root)
[connection] id=CAMPUS | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=CAMPUS | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ACADEMIC-1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ACADEMIC-1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ACADEMIC-1 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/GUEST]] (600 root)
[connection] id=GUEST | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=GUEST | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     1F2BE74683868C04A429DFF
depends:        ath9k_hw,mac80211,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-92-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2A:48:00:B9:4D:C7:83:D0:53:26:FA:E6:7B:01:B0:BE:B7:3B:B8:11
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     93644B269B570BC55CF5154
depends:        ath,ath9k_hw
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-92-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2A:48:00:B9:4D:C7:83:D0:53:26:FA:E6:7B:01:B0:BE:B7:3B:B8:11
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     4D7E3FBEBDFF649364222B3
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-92-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2A:48:00:B9:4D:C7:83:D0:53:26:FA:E6:7B:01:B0:BE:B7:3B:B8:11
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     88A67C5359B02C5A710AFCF
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-92-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2A:48:00:B9:4D:C7:83:D0:53:26:FA:E6:7B:01:B0:BE:B7:3B:B8:11
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     C31A92A72ADA65F2F8247FB
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-92-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2A:48:00:B9:4D:C7:83:D0:53:26:FA:E6:7B:01:B0:BE:B7:3B:B8:11
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[ath3k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
firmware:       ath3k-1.fw
license:        GPL
version:        1.0
description:    Atheros AR30xx firmware driver
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     A49A3D87CA20DB742E336F9
depends:        bluetooth
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-92-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2A:48:00:B9:4D:C7:83:D0:53:26:FA:E6:7B:01:B0:BE:B7:3B:B8:11
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     0055529745EF9A8A3E57FC3
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-92-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2A:48:00:B9:4D:C7:83:D0:53:26:FA:E6:7B:01:B0:BE:B7:3B:B8:11
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
ps_enable: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x168c:0x0036 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[  144.970320] wlan0: failed to insert STA entry for the AP (error -22)
[  161.937647] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[  161.950415] wlan0: failed to insert STA entry for the AP (error -22)
[  172.902514] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[  172.921194] wlan0: failed to insert STA entry for the AP (error -22)

########## wireless info END ############
```

As you can see at the bottom that I am having this error
    **[  172.921194] wlan0: failed to insert STA entry for the AP (error -22)**
I google it but there wasn't much information related to it. I don't know what else to do.

**edit-1**

result of $demsg | grep ath

```
[    1.570858] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: 2a4800b94dc783d05326fae67b01b0beb73bb811'
[   12.713058] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability
[   12.722150] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[   12.724538] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[   12.724543] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
[   12.724545] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   12.724547] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   12.724549] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
[   13.070362] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   18.623950] type=1400 audit(1469858973.553:22): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=908 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.623956] type=1400 audit(1469858973.553:23): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=908 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.623966] type=1400 audit(1469858973.553:26): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-ofono" pid=908 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   74.979745] Modules linked in: cdc_acm bnep rfcomm binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek rndis_host cdc_ether usbnet wl(POX) dell_wmi sparse_keymap uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core rts5139(C) videodev dell_laptop dcdbas intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep arc4 snd_pcm snd_page_alloc ath9k snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ath9k_common ath9k_hw radeon ath snd_rawmidi mac80211 cfg80211 ttm snd_seq ath3k btusb snd_seq_device bluetooth i915 snd_timer snd mei_me drm_kms_helper shpchp lpc_ich serio_raw mei drm soundcore i2c_algo_bit wmi video mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci r8169 libahci mii
[   74.979807]  [<ffffffff8106987d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[   74.979809]  [<ffffffff8106995a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[   74.979922]  [<ffffffff8173a9dd>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
[   76.059740] Modules linked in: cdc_acm bnep rfcomm binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek rndis_host cdc_ether usbnet wl(POX) dell_wmi sparse_keymap uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core rts5139(C) videodev dell_laptop dcdbas intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep arc4 snd_pcm snd_page_alloc ath9k snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ath9k_common ath9k_hw radeon ath snd_rawmidi mac80211 cfg80211 ttm snd_seq ath3k btusb snd_seq_device bluetooth i915 snd_timer snd mei_me drm_kms_helper shpchp lpc_ich serio_raw mei drm soundcore i2c_algo_bit wmi video mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci r8169 libahci mii
[   76.059790]  [<ffffffff8106987d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[   76.059791]  [<ffffffff8106995a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[   76.059901]  [<ffffffff8173a9dd>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
```

I have not attached everything shown by the command as logs were kind of repenting which is usual.

**edit-2**

full output of $demsg | grep ath command, http://pastebin.com/VYbebB2K

Comment: I have tried this solution before asking the question, needless to say it didn't work in my case. Thanks anyway sir, for your immediate reply.

Comment: @Hedwig That's not the same device as you can see from the data provided above.

Comment: May we also see: `dmesg | grep ath`? Please edit your question to add the results.

Comment: I have added the result of dmesg | grep ath

Comment: Here is the full output of the command $demsg | grep ath; just in case http://pastebin.com/VYbebB2K